# AngularJS not reloading jQuery scripts on partials

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-ui

I have to use *Angular UI Bootstrap* for the `datepicker` directives, as well as *Semantic UI* for the modals. In order to resolve the conflict between *Bootstrap* and *Semantic UI* modals, I have to include this in the `partials.html`.

```
<script>
$.fn.bsModal = $.fn.modal.noConflict();
</script>
```

This works great when I load the page the first time.
However when I navigate away from the page and come back, I get an error message in the console, and my scope objects get mucked up, all the `{{{someobject.key}}` code shows up:

```
TypeError: $.fn.modal.noConflict is not a function
```

I have to refresh the page to resolve the problem.

Is there a way to put this in the controller rather than the body of the partials? I tried putting the line in my controller but it didn't work. Same error.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/J34kPph06ezZhLyai4Ci/index.html

Sorry if it's a mess....just cut and pasted chunks from my project here. annotated some parts to explain.

Answer (score 0):

OK, not the best of coding, but a simple solution nonetheless.

I commented out the modal section in the bootstrap JS file by adding /* at the line where it starts.